# Mockito control output returned based off input

Tags: java, mockito

I have issue where when I use Java parallelStream instead of stream my tests fail. This happens because I am returning Mock objects in a strict order rather than controlling Mock objects returned based on input.

The following is my current code used to return mocks objects:

```
when(myOperation.getSomething(any(String.class)))
    .thenAnswer(AdditionalAnswers.returnsElementsOf(aListOfThings)));
```

How can I concisely control the return value based off the argument I am passing to "getSomething"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like that:

```
when(myOperation.getSomething(any(String.class))).thenAnswer(new Answer<SomeThing>() {
    @Override
    public SomeThing answer(final InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
        // HERE ====> use invocation.getArguments()
        return new SomeThing();
    }
});
```

Here the answer return a `SomeThing` instance, you will need to adjust to your needs

Some reading:

- [Java 8 custom answer support](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#37)
- [doAnswer documentation](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#doAnswer(org.mockito.stubbing.Answer))
- [`InvocationOnMock` javadoc](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/invocation/InvocationOnMock.html)

Comment: Thanks! That looks like directly I should be looking in. Should be enough to get me there.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using an Answer, you can just iterate across your values and set up specific stubs for each one. Unlike with an Answer, you have to be able to predict *all* values for which you're stubbed, but for your particular case here it sounds like that might not be a problem.

```
for (int i = 0; i < aListOfThings.size(); i++) {
  when(myOperation.getSomething(aListOfKeys.get(i)))
      .thenReturn(aListOfThings.get(i));
}
```